# Ubuntu Minimal 18.04 Slowness

Tags: intel, ubuntu-minimal, i3-wm

For the first time, I installed Ubuntu Minimal 18.04 and only installed i3wm + polybar as a graphical interface.

I've been setting up my system for three days and learning along the way what I should install for the system to work properly.

But since this morning, when I started the computer for the first time today, the boot occurs quickly, but after I log in to Ubuntu, the polybar bar loads and giving the command to open the terminal (gnome-terminal), it takes a lot of time to respond, so much that I get to give the command again thinking that I had the keys wrong.

Now, just when I turned on the computer for the second time today when I arrived at my office, it is happening again this slowness.

The terminal opens after about 20 seconds, when before in a xubuntu installation using i3wm could say that the opening was immediate. My computer is a thinkpad x250 intel i5 + 8gb ram.

After the terminal opens, other programs such as the Chromium browser open normally and at the usual speed. So I conclude that the slowness is occurring when loading the system.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening?

Did not I install something that should make the system work better? Maybe it's the polybar, it's the first time I use it.

I have not changed any driver on the machine, should I install something to improve performance? Can you tell me how to do it using the command line?

I do not know what log data I need to put here to help with the diagnosis, please help me.

After I installed lm-sensors, Im getting these results: (ambient temp: 22°celsius)

```
fabio@thinkpadx250:~$ sensors
```

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.0°C

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +32.0°C

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3653 RPM

Thank you very much.
(sorry for the English)

Comment: I just checked and the intel-microcode is installed and updated. So it isn't that.

Comment: Have you tried installing and using `xfce4-terminal` to use instead of `gnome-terminal` to see if that is the problem?

Comment: Not yet, just because I noticed the same thing is happening with VLC. I'm doing the backup of my files and after performing a few tests: use the xfce4-terminal and remove the polybar. I let you know the results on a moment. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I did the tests yesterday but the problem persists. So I re-installed Ubuntu Minimal without any other package. After that I installed xorg, slim (login manager) and i3. When I login on the system for the first time the gnome-terminal was slow to open, so I removed it and installed the xfce4-terminal: all good and fast. The VLC I mentioned before is a snap package, now that the version from the repository is installed it's all good as well. But gedit is very slow, so I'm using xed. My conclusion so far is that the gnome applications are slowing down. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just remembered now, the computer is getting pretty high temperatures, like 90° celsius on an 20-25° ambient while playing youtube. If it helps.

Comment: Is this using Intel graphics? I have had some problems in the past when the graphics card was not properly detected and the system was reporting "Gallium" incorrectly and this caused problems. However, before you do anything else, please run the following commands to install `lm-sensors` and to detect all of your sensors to make sure stuff like the fan is working properly as well: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install lm-sensors; sudo sensors-detect` and then answer Yes to all of the questions that it asks.

Comment: I added the results for the sensors on the question. Im using Intel graphics indeed. Intel HD 5500.

Comment: I don't think that this is a temperature issue. I have an Avell notebook running Ubuntu 18.04 with i3-wm and it uses to get to high temperatures like 90º too but gnome-terminal works just fine here.
Usually when your cpu temperatures get too high (above 100º), the problem you will face is your machine unexpectedly halting on it's own but no slowness in any application. That's what was happening to my note before I changed the thermal paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the issue. So I installed Xubuntu and after i3wm, now it isn't heating.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions!